# R : replace elements in different columns after multiple comparisons

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a raw survey data `df` with 7 items from 5 people. One item (not the same item) for each individual is a subject of a comparison. A vector `vec` indicates the location of the item. Also, there are two matrices `prob1` `prob2` used for the comparison. The comparison is that if a random value is lower than the value in the same location with the item in `prob1`, the raw survey response is replaced with 9. If the random value is between the values from `prob1` and `prob2`, the raw survey response is replace with 99.

In the example below, for the first respondent, the response of item 3, which is `3`, is a subject of the comparison. The corresponding value from `prob1` and `prob2` are `.103`, and `.781`. Because a random number for the first respondent, `.482` is between the two value, the initial data for the first respondent needs to be replaced with 99.

I can certainly do it using for-loop, but it goes slowly. I tried to use `sapply` function, but I really did not get the right solution. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
set.seed(100)
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),35,replace=T),nrow=5))
vec<-c(3,5,2,3,1)
set.seed(1)
prob1<-round(matrix(runif(35,0,.5), nrow=5),3)
set.seed(2)
prob2<-round(matrix(runif(35,.51,1), nrow=5),3)
ran<-c(.482, .298, .115, .163, .644)

> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 1  2  2  3  3  3  1  2
 2  2  4  4  1  3  4  4
 3  3  3  2  2  3  4  2
 4  1  3  3  2  3  3  4
 5  3  1  4  3  2  2  3
> prob1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] 0.133 0.449 0.103 0.249 0.467 0.193 0.241
[2,] 0.186 0.472 0.088 0.359 0.106 0.007 0.300
[3,] 0.286 0.330 0.344 0.496 0.326 0.191 0.247
[4,] 0.454 0.315 0.192 0.190 0.063 0.435 0.093
[5,] 0.101 0.031 0.385 0.389 0.134 0.170 0.414
> prob2
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] 0.601 0.972 0.781 0.928 0.834 0.749 0.515
[2,] 0.854 0.573 0.627 0.988 0.700 0.583 0.591
[3,] 0.791 0.918 0.883 0.621 0.920 0.685 0.907
[4,] 0.592 0.739 0.599 0.728 0.584 0.982 0.936
[5,] 0.972 0.779 0.709 0.547 0.680 0.575 0.762
```

Comment: And if the random value is greater than `prob1` and `prob2`, then is the raw survey response left untouched?

Comment: yes. Nothing needs to be done, if the value is greater than both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to access the following the following indices

```
idx <- cbind(seq_along(vec),c(vec))
```

and you want to change `df` where

```
ind99 <- ran < prob2[idx] 
ind09 <- ran < prob1[idx]
```

so

```
df[idx[ind99,]] <- 99
df[idx[ind09,]] <-  9
```

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  2  2 99  3  3  1  2
2  2  4  4  1 99  4  4
3  3  9  2  2  3  4  2
4  1  3  9  2  3  3  4
5 99  1  4  3  2  2  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Because I am not an expert in R, I didn't really get how `prob2[idx]` returns the corresponding five probabilities, `0.781 0.700 0.918 0.599 0.972` Could you please explain it?

Comment: Look at the help file for indexing `?'['`, the section beginning, "A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column for each dimension."

Comment: Got it. I hope to vote your answer a million times. Thanks much!!